# Java SQL Exception when creating a DSNless connection

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, odbc

Here is my code:

```
package dsnless;
import java.sql.*;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//This class will be used to fire queries to the database
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class Query {
    public Query(){
        String pathToDatabase = "E:/Eclipse Projects/JDBC/src/datasouce/School.mdb";
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver="+
                      "{Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb,*.accdb)};" +
                      ":DBQ=" + pathToDatabase;
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(database);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Query();
    }
    Connection con;
    Statement s;
    ResultSet r;
}//class Query end
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] DRIVER keyword syntax error
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dsnless.Query.<init>(Query.java:14)
    at dsnless.Query.main(Query.java:20)
```

And there is a new exception, too:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dsnless.Query.<init>(Query.java:14)
    at dsnless.Query.main(Query.java:20)
```

### Question

Please tell me what is wrong. I suspect it is the `String database` but stil it is only a guess.

## Nailed it, myself

I changed the extensions supported from `(*.mdb,*.accdb)` to only `(*.mdb)` and it worked. Any idea as to why that happened???

Comment: Might be an issue with the space in the path. Also, is `datasouce` a misspelling or thats what one of the folders is actually named

Comment: try using backslashes for the file path and include double quotes  to mask the space: `pathToDatabase = "\"E:\\Eclipse Project\\JDBC\\src\\datasouce\\... \""` (and get rid of the colon as pointed out by reimeus)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name heehaw!! go over the edit and see the section `Nailed it, Myself`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an additional colon here, remove it

```
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver="+
              "{Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb,*.accdb)};" +
              ":DBQ=" + pathToDatabase;
               ^
```

Comment: Error was with the extension. Please go over the section `Nailed it, myself`

Comment: Looks like your driver doesnt support the [ACCDB format](http://databases.about.com/od/access/a/accdb.htm)

Comment: So, how can I add support for ACCDB file?

Comment: What version of MS Access are you using?

Comment: 32 bit version from Office 2010